# Is it possible to send parallel requests from one Websocket connection?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm actually using [WebSockets 7](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and everything goes fine, multiple users can connect to the websocket, send requests and receive responses from server, but there is a *problem*.

If a user send to image, pdf, song, video, etc. Server must resolve that, saving to db, converting, etc, and sending response, the user could send more data to websocket but that data will be queued until previous message got response, that is not good, when users are desperate to send data in shortest time possible.

There is a possibility for a user connected to send *parallel requests*?

This is the example I'm using

```
import asyncio
import websockets

# Process the data
async def read(msg, websocket):
    # In this case, the message will get back to the user
    await websocket.send(msg)

async def counter(websocket, path):
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            await read(message, websocket)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        pass

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        websockets.serve(counter, '0.0.0.0', 4444, max_size=10**8))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
```

### Update

I'm using the loop, in the trying to make a request in parallel, it does not work though.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

# Process the data
async def read(msg, websocket):
    # In this case, the message will get back to the user
    if msg == 'long':
        # Some blocking operations
        pass
    elif msg == 'short':
        # Some blocking operations
        pass
    # elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        # Some blocking operations
        # pass
    # elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        # Some blocking operations
        # pass
    # elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        # Some blocking operations
        # pass
    # elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        # Some blocking operations
       # pass

    print("Did a {0} task".format(msg))
    await websocket.send(msg)

async def counter(websocket, path):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            loop.create_task(read(message, websocket))
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        pass

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        websockets.serve(counter, '0.0.0.0', 4444, max_size=10**8))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
```

When user send 'long', and then send 'short', "long" will make "short" wait until it is processed. :(

If add `await asyncio.sleep()` inside every condition, it will take parallelously but longest task must have longest time for `asyncio.sleep()`
eg:

```
    if msg == 'this is probably the longest task to do':
        await asyncio.sleep(5);
        # Some blocking operations
    elif msg == 'this is probably the shortest task to do':
        await asyncio.sleep(1);
        # Some blocking operations
    elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        await asyncio.sleep(4);
        # Some blocking operations
    elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        await asyncio.sleep(2);
        # Some blocking operations
    elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        await asyncio.sleep(3);
        # Some blocking operations
    elif msg == 'some other conditions that could take more or less time':
        await asyncio.sleep(1);
        # Some blocking operations
```

If I remove `await asyncio.sleep()`, code will run non-parallelously

Comment: You cannot use `time.sleep` in an asyncio app, it blocks the whole event loop. Switch to `await asyncio.sleep(5)` and see if it works then.

Comment: I did it, and not works.

Comment: Now you seem to be missing an `await` before `asyncio.sleep(5)`.

Comment: Now, testing it...

Comment: When inside "long" condition I add `await asyncio.sleep()`, the second request "short" doesn't have to wait, that's great but I need all posible conditions to be parallel, I mean if I have 50 conditions, every condition should run in "background" to avoid queue-ing. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If I remove `await asyncio.sleep()`, keeps normal execution(in order, and queue-ing)

Comment: My answer should work as you described, regardless of the number of messages. Do you have a concrete issue with the code, or a reason to believe it wouldn't work in some case?

Comment: Edited question

Comment: I was thinking about using `Thread` but seems like `Thread` does not handle async functions to `await` something

Comment: If your point is that you call blocking functions that take a long time to compute, replace the blocking call with `await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_function)`

Comment: I have to put `await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_function)` inside send function? or inside `for` in `counter`?

Comment: Now, `loop.run_in_executor()` does not handle async functions, WebSockets7 works with asyncio, `websocket.send()` must be awaited.

Comment: It's fine to mix them. To call sync functions, call `await loop.run_in_executor(None, sync_function)`. To call async functions, simply await them with `await async_function()`. That covers everything, and you don't need an explicit thread.

Comment: I will test it :/

Comment: No way. It seems like WebSockets cannot receive parallel request from one user connection.

Comment: Every condition leads blocking process mandatorily

Answer (score 1):

Instead of awaiting `read`, you can have `counter` spawn the `read` coroutine in the "background":

```
async def counter(websocket, path):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            loop.create_task(read(message, websocket))
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        pass
```

That way taking the time to respond to a message won't delay responding to subsequent messages.

On an unrelated note, I'd recommend renaming the `read` coroutine to a name more appropriate for what it does, e.g. `handle` or `respond`.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Have you tried adding some prints or debugging in some other way?

Comment: I tried putting print when socket is about to respond, but first request which is bigger, made the second request wait.